# Method [validate] does not exist error в laravel 5

Tags: laravel, авторизация, аутентификация

Здравствуйте

Пытаюсь сделать аутентификацию в Ларавел, но после заполнений полей в форме авторизации выскакивает ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и там ниже куча целая всего еще - как снежный ком...

Вот так прописаны роуты:

```
// Маршруты аутентификации...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
// Маршруты регистрации...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

А сама ошибка возникает на этом месте:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

Не пойму, где мне взять этот метод validate?
Потому что создавалось все не вручную, а просто с помощью `php artisan make:auth`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот метод есть в трейте `\Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests`, который должен быть подключен в основном контроллере `\App\Http\Controllers\Controller`.

Если что-то убирали - верните. Или просто добавьте `use ValidatesRequests` в контроллер.

Comment: Уже подлючено
`namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources;
use App\Models\Flats;`

Comment: То, что вы скопировали - это подключение namespace'ов. Внутри класса тоже должно быть ``use ValidatesRequests;``

Comment: Спасибо огромное, случайно видимо строчка захватилась при комментировании, Невнимательность..