# laravel 6 Method validate does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Есть код:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $var = 'create';

        return view('services.index', ['data' => $var, ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $data = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);
        $name = request('name');
        DB::table('services')->insert(['name' => $name]);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

путь: `Route::post('/service', 'ServiceController@store');` 
и форма:

```
@extends('html')

@section('title', 'create')

@section('content')

    <h1>Create service</h1>
    <form action='/service' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='name'>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button>Add service</button>
    </form>

@endsection
```

После отправки формы пытаюсь сделать валидацию но выбивает ошибку:

```
BadMethodCallException
Method validate does not exist.
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: composer upgrade и/или composer dumpautoload

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Method \[validate\] does not exist error в laravel 5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586729/method-validate-does-not-exist-error-%d0%b2-laravel-5)

Comment: composer uprade и dumpautoload не помогло, насчёт дубликата вот код такой как и там                                                                       <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}

Comment: Когда вы используете trait ValidatesRequests, он по сути добавляет методы в класс. Вместо $request-> в этом случае нужно использовать $this-> (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184162/method-validate-does-not-exist)

Comment: помогло, а как сделать чтобы можно было обращатся через $request-> или вот так request()->validate([])

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

```html
$data = request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Или это

```html
$this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Comment: уже пробовал не помогло

Comment: думаю вы уже нашли. Или попробуйте 2-вариант. Проверил у меня работает как надо.

Comment: да, второй вариант работает нормально

Comment: Ответ на вышестоящий вопрос. Вам нужно убрать 'Request $request' из метода store(). Тогда будут работать оба варианта которые вы хотели.

Comment: В том то и дело что нет, я уже пробовал так. Если убрать 'Request $request', то в первом случае пишет что не оределена переменная $request, а во втором request()->validate([]) таже ошибка: метод не существует. Хотя смотрю видео урок там пишут именно так request()->validate([]) без 'Request $request' в методе store и всё работает.